# Windows 10 Universal app - xaml strange issues

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml

I have locator view model:

```
namespace PassStore.Universal.ViewModels
{
    ....
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
         public NewDatabaseViewModel NewDatabase =>   
                 this.container.Resolve<NewDatabaseViewModel>();
    }
}
```

In app.xaml:

```
 ..
 xmlns:viewModels="using:PassStore.Universal.ViewModels"
 ..

<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Application-specific resources -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" ></viewModels:ViewModelLocator>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But I get compile-time error that ViewModelLocator doesn't exist in specified namespace. What can I do?

Comment: I've come across this issue. After building the project, the error disappeared.

Comment: Try like this ... <viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" xmlns:viewModels="using:PassStore.Universal.ViewModels" /> hope this will solve error

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild your  project (right click in Solution Explorer on your project and choose 'Rebuild')